# Bind to inner values of a property

Tags: java, syntax, java-8

Suppose we have a label `labelName` and a current player property `CurrentPlayerProperty` which is a `ObjectProperty`. We want to bind the current player's name to the label, but doing this:

```
labelName.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("Name: ", CurrentPlayerProperty().getValue().getName()));
```

doesn't change the label after`CurrentPlayerProperty` was changed. This is probably because it's bound to the name of the first player.

Is there a way to do this without making a special property for the name?

I ask because there are more details that needs to be bound beside the name and it seems like a lot of code duplication to have for each of them a special property.